# Scala : NodeSeq to Map

Tags: scala

I can't grasp the `map` method I guess..

Trying to read a file :

```
val messagesMap = XML.loadFile(messageXMLFile).map(parseMessageXML)
```

where the method `parseMessageXML` is defined as :

```
def parseMessageXML(xml : scala.xml.Node) = {

    val nodes = xml \\ "add"

    nodes.map({
      node =>
        val obj = new AdMessage(node)
        println("adding an AdMessage " + obj.toString)
        (obj.MessageId -> obj)
    }).toMap

  }
```

Can anybody please explain why I end up with a `Seq[Map[String, AdMessage]]` and not a just a `Map[String, AdMessage]` ?

Comment: Try `val messagesMap = parseMessageXML(XML.loadFile(messageXMLFile))`

Comment: @PeterNeyens that s it.. can you maybe add it as an answer with some explanation on what I am doing wrong in the snippet above with the map(). and toMap()?

Answer (score 2):

`map` transforms each element of your `Seq` into an another element.

For instance:

```
scala> Seq("One", "Two", "Three").map(_.length())
res0: Seq[Int] = List(3, 3, 5)
```

Each `String` is ***mapped*** into an `Int` thanks to the `length` function. Therefore the original type is `Seq[String]` and the final type is `Seq[Int]`

In your case, `parseMessageXML` transforms a `Node` into a `Map[String, AdMessage]`, so the original type is `Seq[Node]` and the final type is `Seq[Map[String, AdMessage]]`.

In your case, assuming you just want to transform the content of the file into a `Map[String, AdMessage]`:

```
val messagesMap = parseMessageXML(XML.loadFile(messageXMLFile))
```